# Making ScaLAPACK - Error in blacstest.f: undefined reference to `dwalltime00_'

Tags: scalapack

I'm having a hard time trying to set up ScaLAPACK. I cannot find any similar error anywhere.

I have downloaded scalapack 2.2.0 from their website, I have set up the SLmake.inc and typed *make* in my terminal.

I paste here the error I get

```
mpif90 -fallow-argument-      mismatch -O3  -o xCbtest   blacstest.o btprim.o tools.o   Cbt.o ../../libscalapack.a
/usr/bin/ld: blacstest.o: in function `auxtest_':
blacstest.f:(.text+0x9948): undefined reference to `dwalltime00_'
/usr/bin/ld: blacstest.f:(.text+0x995b): undefined reference to `dwalltime00_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:19: xCbtest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/my/directory/scalapack-2.2.0/BLACS/TESTING'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8: tester] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/my/directory/scalapack-2.2.0/BLACS'
make: *** [Makefile:74: blacsexe] Error 2
```

I don't even know what does that mean....I would appreciate any help. Thank you!!